# GCP App Engine instance cannot connect to GCP Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

App engine config:

```yaml
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
```

NodeJs application running: (i) Apollo server, (ii) Express, (iii) Knex

Steps:

1. Get the Public IP Address of Cloud SQL Instance
2. Get the Connection Name of Cloud SQL Instance
3. Set the Connection Name of the Cloud SQL Instance in `app.yaml`
4. Set the Public IP Address of the Cloud SQL Instance in `index.ts` of client

`index.ts`

```
// @note Using Knex
const db = await initDatabase({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host: args['blockchain-db-host'],
      port: args['blockchain-db-port'],
      database: args['blockchain-db-database'],
      user: args['blockchain-db-user'],
      password: args['blockchain-db-pass'],
    },
  })
```

N.B.
Also get `Username`, `Password`, and set them in `index.ts`, also `Port` in `index.ts` used as `5432` as Cloud SQL Instance is a Postgres database.

`app.yaml`

```
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <project>:<region>:<sql-instance>=tcp:5432
```

N.B.
The `beta_settings` once deployed via `gcloud app deploy` is not reflected in config file on Google App Engine. Also, I am not familiar with the Unix socket methodology, I am assuming that `5432` should also be used as the `PORT` when setting up the App engine's cloud proxy connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the Application is a flex environment, App Engine is allowed to connect to Cloud SQL via: (i) TCP, and (ii) Unix Socket

N.B. In my case, I would advise to use the `Unix Socket` in conjunction with `Connection Instance`, otherwise, use of IP Addresses typically require whitelisting and other configuration.

If you are using the `Connection Instance Name` provided by the Cloud SQL Instance, you should be using the `Unix Socket` methodology to establish the connection.

In this case, `app.yaml` must have:

```
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <project>:<region>:<sql-instance>=tcp:5432
```

And `index.ts` must resemble:

```
const db = await initDatabase({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host: `/cloudsql/${args['blockchain-sql-connection-name']}`,
      port: args['blockchain-db-port'],
      database: args['blockchain-db-database'],
      user: args['blockchain-db-user'],
      password: args['blockchain-db-pass'],
    },
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggesting following the instructions in the documentation: [Connecting to Cloud SQL from App Engine (Flex).](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-flexible)

Specifically with your `app.yaml`, you need to connect with `172.17.0.1:PORT`, where PORT is the port you specified (`5432`). This is because the Cloud SQL Auth proxy is listening on 172.17.0.1 to encrypt and forward connections to your Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this but also ready somewhere that connecting using IP address over Unix socket connection strings required IP allow listing of the GAE instance's IP address to be allowed in the connection settings of the Cloud SQL instance. You can see my answer for what I ended up going with as a result of the findings mentioned here.

Comment: @matabeitt your answer looks incorrect as is because you have added `=tcp:5432` in your app.yaml. If you want to use a unix socket you need to remove that argument.